# How to reuse view controller for a process of multiple screens?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an application that is a kind of chat, that asks some questions and where the user can answer to.

Each question has it's own screen and after the user has replied to the question, there is a button that navigates to the next screen.

All the screens are barely the same. A UILabel and input field. Now I was wondering if there is a way to reuse this view, so I don't have to create multiple view controllers that are exactly the same.

Is this possible and for what should I looking for?

Comment: you can use container view load your common viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the following way:

1. Create your variables in the reuse view controller:

   ```
   var question: String!
   ```
2. The button action needs to perform the segue:

   ```
   @IBAction func nextQuestionAction() {
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "NextQuestionSegue", sender: nil)
   }
   ```
3. In the prepare for segue, before transitioning, you assign the next question:

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
       if segue.identifier == "NextQuestionSegue" {
           guard let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ReuseViewController else { return }
           destinationVC.question = "Question goes here"
       }
   }
   ```

This is how it would work.

Answer (score 0):

For how I imagine it you have a flow of screens inside a PageViewController `QuestionsViewController`. So what you can do it to have one UIViewController `TitleInputViewController` that exposes closures for the UITextViewDelegate and the answer submit action callbacks and two properties, one for UILabel and one for the UIField.

- `var textFieldDidChangeCallback: (String?) -> Void`: can use for showing field verification messages
- `var didSubmitAnswerCallback: (String?) -> Void`: can use to show field verifications messages and/or show next/previous controller
- `@IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!`: can use to set the title text, font and text color
- `@IBOutlet var inputField: UITextField!`: can use to set the title text, font, verification error messages and text color

Then you let this `QuestionsViewController` create however many instances of this `TitleInputViewController`, manage and show them using those callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible.

You can instantiate your ViewControllers programmatically and push them in your navigation controller or present it the way you want. To do this you can use:

```
let nextVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "formViewController")
```

Where "Main" is the name of your storyboard and the identifier is the one you set for that page on that storyboard.

Now that you have our viewController (cast it to your specific type `as! FormViewController` ) you can set the properties as you wish. (The text of your label or the delegate of your TextField.)

If you have a fix order of these forms then you can also put multiple VCs on your storyboard, link them together and set the class of them to the same ViewController class. Then connect the outlets to the same fields in that VC.